# (base) cat command doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, cat

as a newcomer to the world of Ubuntu, I was testing cat command. After creating a file with JOE, I tried to see its content with cat.

```
(base) someone@computer:~$ cat sth.txt
```

However, the result is:

```
command(base) someone@computer:~$
```

Nothing displayed. When I tried creating a file with `cat >newfile` - this command succeeded and I could read the created file using cat. Nevertheless, why can't I read other files, not created with cat? I know that I work in conda environment (`(base) someone@computer`), but I have no idea (except quitting conda) how can I solve the problem.

Comment: What was actually in `sth.txt`?

Comment: Do I have to delete a question with such a ridiculous answer or it can be stored for the next generations?

Comment: The allegedly ridiculous answer gets upvoted. Let the question stay.

Answer (score 3):

The solution turned out to be simpler than posting a question.

The file contained the word

> command

without a newline at the end, thus it was displayed in a single row with `someone@computer:~$`.